# How to add an anchor tag <a> to a block of html?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, anchor

I have a block of html that I want to act as a clickable link. In the block of code below, I would like to make the whole div into a link.

```
<div id="clickableLink">
    <h3>Link Heading</h3>
    <img src="linkPic.jpg" alt="Link alt text" width="65" height="65" />
</div>
```

HTML5 permits surrounding the html in an anchor tag (I think). See below

```
<a href="goThere.html">
    <div id="clickableLink">
        <h3>Link Heading</h3>
        <img src="linkPic.jpg" alt="Link alt text" width="65" height="65" />
    </div>
</a>
```

However, this seems wrong to me. How will software such as screen readers describe the link.

I also considered the following CSS trick. I altered the HTML to be

```
<div id="clickableLink">
    <h3>Link Heading</h3>
    <img src="linkPic.jpg" alt="Link alt text" width="65" height="65" />
    <a href="goThere.html"></a>
</div>
```

and then used CSS to style the link to cover the whole of the div. See below:

```
#clickableLink {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 0;
}

h3 {
    z-index: 0;
}

img {
    z-index: 0;
}

a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This works perfectly in all browsers apart from IE. Does anyone else have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that will allow older browsers to render it properly (and to make sure it validates) is to use inherently inline elements inside an inline element. In other words, block level elements can not be placed inside inline ones (according to the HTML, not the values that CSS may give the element). You can then use CSS to make a span act like it is block level. So the markup could easily be:

```
<a href="goThere.html">
    <span id="clickableLink">
        <span class="headerthree">Link Heading</span>
        <img src="linkPic.jpg" alt="Link alt text" width="65" height="65" />
    </span>
</a>
```

If you declare that the A is block level, then you wouldn't even need the span. Problem here is that you lose the SEO of using Header elements. So...

The best thing is probably to leave it specced for HTML5 as you have it above, even though it seems wrong. To help SEO and screen readers, use a title tag to "describe" the anchor. The code will validate just fine. Then, make sure your A is display: block, and I *think* older browsers will render it ok, too.

Comment: Thanks. Since asking the question, I have also found this resource:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20101014/H2

It demonstrates best practice for accessibility. It is nearly identical to what you have above. All you need to make sure is that the 'Link alt text' does not repeat the heading.

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach is actually the best.  To describe your link, you should use the `a` element's attributes such as title, alt and possibly any WAI-ARIA markup you wanted to employ.  This is good industry practice anyway and allows you to wrap content in an `a` tag without worrying about accessibility.